# How to calculate year and gpa in sql using jdbc?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I need to search for students by GPA in java and use jbdc to connect to the database following the requirements in the attached image.

[image]

These are the tables I have in the database:

```
 CREATE TABLE Students (
 first_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
 last_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
 id VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (id)
 );



 CREATE TABLE Classes (
 name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
 credits INT NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (name)
 ); 

 CREATE TABLE IsTaking (
 sid VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL,
 name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
 FOREIGN KEY (sid) REFERENCES Students(id),
 FOREIGN KEY (name) REFERENCES Classes(name)
 );



 CREATE TABLE HasTaken (
 sid VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL,
 name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
 grade CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
 FOREIGN KEY (sid) REFERENCES Students(id),
 FOREIGN KEY (name) REFERENCES Classes(name)
 );
```

And this is the java code I have written:

```
public static void searchByGPAGreaterThan(Connection conn, Scanner input)  throws SQLException {
    // Construct the SQL query to select the ID, first name, and last name of all students
    // who have taken at least one course and whose GPA is greater than or equal to the threshold.
    System.out.print("Enter GPA threshold: ");
    double threshold = input.nextDouble();
    String query = "SELECT Students.first_name, Students.last_name, Students.id, Classes.credits FROM Students, Classes " +
            "WHERE id IN (SELECT sid FROM HasTaken " + "GROUP BY sid HAVING SUM(CASE grade " +
            "WHEN 'A' THEN 4 " +
            "WHEN 'B' THEN 3 " +
            "WHEN 'C' THEN 2 " +
            "WHEN 'D' THEN 1 " +
            "ELSE 0 END * credits) / SUM(credits) >= ?)";
    try {
        // Create a prepared statement for the query and set the threshold parameter.
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        ps.setDouble(1, threshold);
        // Execute the query and get the result set.
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        // Print out the results.
        while (rs.next()) {
            int id = rs.getInt("id");
            String firstName = rs.getString("first_name");
            String lastName = rs.getString("last_name");
            System.out.printf("%d: %s %s\n", id, firstName, lastName);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // If there is an error executing the query, print the stack trace.
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This code outputs all the students instead of specific students with the specified gpa threshold value. I can't figure out how to correctly calculate the student gpa so that the output only prints the appropriate students.

I had to populate the database with data for 100 students so I will provide sample data for one student for context:

```
INSERT INTO Classes (name, credits) VALUES
('Calculus I', 4),
('Introduction to Biology', 3),
('World History', 3);

INSERT INTO Students (first_name, last_name, id) VALUES
('Amabelle', 'Jimmes', '10000');

INSERT INTO IsTaking (sid, name) VALUES
(10000, 'Introduction to Biology'),
(10000, 'Calculus I'),
(10000, 'World History');

INSERT INTO HasTaken (sid, name, grade) VALUES
(10000, 'Introduction to Biology', 'A'),
(10000, 'Calculus I', 'B'),
(10000, 'World History', 'C');
```

Comment: what is the data that you get from a sql workbench?

Comment: I updated the post with sample data

Answer (score 0):

I would change the query so that it returns the raw data (per student) to the java classes which then does the necessary calculation

```
select s.*, group_concat(case ht.grade when 'A' then 4 when 'B' then 3 when 'C' then 2 when 'D' then 1 end) grade from Students s
join HasTaken ht on ht.sid = s.id
join Classes c on c.name = ht.name
group by s.id
;
```

will produce

```
first_name  last_name   id  grade
Amabelle    Jimmes  10000   4,3,2
```

Comment: When I change the query to your suggestion, I receive an error after I type in the user input for gpa threshold. The error is " Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0)."

Comment: Yeah , I think that you believe that you need to get this type of raw data back to Java and then use it to sum and filter using the input gpa, so yeah there is there is no parameters being passed to it.  There may be situations where performing calculations on the client side is more appropriate. For example, if your application needs to perform complex calculations that are not supported by the database